# Rotation When Object is Spinning

Tags: three.js, physijs

**[]**              **[]**

Imagine those are the front tires of a car and they're spinning forward in a straight line.  How would I rotate them (in a steering motion) without them being affected by their local (spinning) rotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a "wheel" to a THREE.Group() object and rotate the group on y-axis.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < wheels.length; i++){
    steering[i].rotation.y = Math.sin(new Date() * 0.005) * 0.25;
    wheels[i].rotation.x += 0.1;
  }
```

each `steering` is a THREE.Group(), each `wheels` is a cylinder.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/smrLf77m/) example

Comment: It's an excellent answer to the question and I'm not asking you to take it any further, but it won't work with physijs objects because you can't group 'em like that.

Comment: @fallingCode Oh! thanks for reminding me about Physijs ) I wanted to try it before already)

Comment: LOL, no problem..  if anyone else has a suggestion for a physijs solution, drop a reply.  I have some ideas that may work.  I think it's just gonna take some creativity to achieve my goal.  I'll post my solution.