# Rotate wheels on 2 axis in Three.JS

Tags: vector, three.js, rotation

I'm trying to rotate object on two axis y and x.
But it does not work properly.
Here is example

https://imge.to/i/vqyt20 local axis (no rotations)

https://imge.to/i/vqypnA what I have after moving with rotations

```
wheel1.rotation.x += movement;
wheel1.rotation.y = angle;
```

PS it works when `movement == 0` or `angle == 0` but fails when they both are not 0.

I've tried to use quaternions and multiply rotation vectors but nothing helps. Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

I've found answer on my question with vector rotation around y-axis

```
 angleX += movement; 

    [wheel1, wheel2].forEach(function (wheel) {
        let vector = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        vector.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), angleY);

        wheel.rotation.y = angleY;
        wheel.rotation.x = 0;
        wheel.rotation.z = 0;

        wheel.rotateOnWorldAxis(vector, angleX);
    });
```

**ONE MORE SOLUTION** given in comments is to change `wheel.rotation` to `'YXZ'` 
[How to Rotate an Object and Reset it's Rotation to Zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774633/how-to-rotate-an-object-and-reset-its-rotation-to-zero/14776900#14776900)

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395484/4045502)

Comment: @prisoner849 I know this method, but thats quite a cheating for real physics

Comment: @OlegPatron See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774633/how-to-rotate-an-object-and-reset-its-rotation-to-zero/14776900#14776900 and set `rotation.order = 'YXZ'`.